# How to move between JSP with NEXT and BACK buttons?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I work on an online examination prject using servlets and JSP. The Admin can add exams which contain questions with their options. The first JSP is when he adds the first question . it contains only the next button .The last JSP contains only the back button and others contain the next and back buttons. Each Exam has 5 questions. My problem is how to move between these JSP using the buttons. Here is my code, i don't know why it doesn't work

```
// Servlet code:
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    int i=1;
    String button1=request.getParameter("back");
    String button2=request.getParameter("next");
    if(button1!=null){
        i=i-1;
    }
    if (button2!=null){
        i=i+1;
    }
    if(i==1 ){
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/AddFirstQuestion.jsp").forward( request, response );
    }
    else if (i==5  ){
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/AddLastQuestion.jsp").forward( request, response );

    }
    else if (i>1 && i<5){
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/AddQuestion.jsp").forward( request, response );
    }

}
```

and there is a part of JSP code:

```
<input type="submit" name ="next" value="Suivant"  />
```

Comment: JSP is a serverside technology and does not know about which button was clicked on the browser's toolbar. The closest you could do is use javascript to get the clicked button and pass it down to your jsp page as a request parameter - but why would anyone do that?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're JSP code snippet isn't visible, Try making a form method and inside set to method as "post" . I'm not sure about using getServletRequest. Try using this one.

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("AddLastQuestion.jsp");
dispatcher.forward( request, response );
```

Also, you're not getting the "back" attribute. Just the next attribute is received for the servlet to process. Hence, the button2 will be always set to null.
Try doing like this. JSP

```
<input type="submit" name ="next" value="Suivant"  />
<input type="submit" name ="back" value="Suivant"  />
```

On the server side, Servlet

```
if(i==1 ){
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("AddLastQuestion.jsp");
dispatcher.forward( request, response );

}
else if (i==5  ){
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("AddLastQuestion.jsp");
dispatcher.forward( request, response );


}
```